# Expressionengine tags inside php

Tags: php, expressionengine

In expressionengine with php parse enabled,

if i do the following, it works and i get the username displayed. logged in user is admin. So it echos out admin.

```
<?php
  $x = '{username}';
  echo $x;
?>
```

However if i do the following and use the{username} tag insde `mkdir()` function, then it doesn't work. The directory created will have the name `{username}` instead of admin. Why is this happening.

```
<?php
  $x = '{username}';
  mkdir($x);
?>
```

Comment: @erisco. EE is open source. That's not the point of the question.

Comment: Well then, where do I freely download the source code for EE? If I can, I will be able to answer your question.

Comment: EE is open source, but not free.  You need to have EE to know what i'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest writing a quick [plugin](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/plugins.html) that accepts the logged-in username as a parameter, then does your `mkdir()` work within the plugin.

```
class Make_directory
{
    var return_data = '';

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->EE =& get_instance();
        $username = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('username', FALSE);

        if($username != FALSE)
        {
            $dir = mkdir(escapeshellarg($username));
        }

        $this->return_data = $dir;
}
```

There's more to the plugin, but that's the guts of it. Then call it like `{exp:make_directory username="{logged_in_username}"}`.

Comment: Thanks @D-rock, i do not really need a plugin. I'm parsing php inside the template and i want to use username inside my php code.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that you might have better luck if you move this to a plugin as opposed to using PHP in your template. Easier to debug, as it's all pure PHP, and my guess is that it will just work.

Answer (score 1):

Expression engine is a templating engine. It almost certainly buffers output then replaces it, which is why this will work with `echo` but not functions.

I'm not an expert in EE, but something like this might work:

```
$name = get_instance()->TMPL->fetch_param('username', '');
mkdir(escapeshellarg($name));
```

The point is you need to get the return of EE interpreting that, rather than just passing the raw text.

You can also use [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/ob_start) to capture the output if you can't easily get EE's return. For example:

```
function mkdir_obcb($dir) {
    mkdir(escapeshellarg($dir));
    return '';
}

ob_start('mkdir_obcb');
echo '{username}';
ob_end_clean();
```

Note also my use of [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) to reduce the risk of attack.

Comment: thanks. Your first solution does not work with expressionengine.  In your second solution how are we creating a directory. I only see echo. How are you passing the {username} to mkdir and where is it called.

Comment: `ob_start()` accepts as its first parameter a callback function. This callback function is called when the output buffer is flushed -- that is, destroyed, cleaned, ended. The callback, in turn, receives as its first parameter whatever was output to the buffer. I am doubtful this will work as a solution, however, as even if EE uses an output buffer, its processing will only occur when its own buffer is ended -- which is after the buffer we made ends, and therefore will not happen until after `mkdir_obcb()` is called.

Comment: in your first example. how do we get the username. In your example username is empty. This echos nothing.

Comment: I'm not sufficiently familiar with EE to know precisely what you need. Perhaps `get_instance()->TMPL->parse_variables('{username}')` will work better? I'm afraid I can't help further as I don't have the knowledge. http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/index.html may be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have it set up so your PHP is being parsed before the EE tags? Not only do you need to set to allow php parsing but what order it happens in as well.

http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/php_templates.html

Comment: That's not the issue. If you look at my 2 examples above, It works for echo but not with mkdir(). I already tried php parse with both options (input and output) as per your link

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set 'PHP Parsing Stage' to 'output' in the preferences of your template in the CP Template Manager, because then PHP executes after expression engine rendered the ee tags.