# ExpressionEngine SAEF File upload to specific directoy

Tags: php, expressionengine

I am using expressionsengine 2.x and trying to create an file upload form for the front-end user where the file uploaded will be stored in a folder named after the logged in userid. Can we do this using saef or safecracker. If not are there other options.

Answer (score 1):

SafeCracker comes bundled with a fieldtype, [SafeCracker File](http://barrettnewton.com/safecracker/user_guide/#section_fieldtypes), for creating file upload fields. The fieldtype leverages any [File Upload Directories](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/admin/content_admin/file_upload_preferences.html) you've created in the Control Panel.

By default, all files uploaded will be stored in the directory specified in the File Upload Directory's preferences.

In order to have SafeCracker files uploaded into a sub-folder *named after the logged in userid*, you could develop a custom add-on, or leverage a [compatible fieldtype that works with SafeCracker](http://barrettnewton.com/safecracker/user_guide/#section_compatibility) -- if one exists to suit your needs.

An alternative to SafeCracker would be to use the [Solspace Freeform Module](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/freeform/). However, even in doing so, your file uploads would still all be saved to the same File Upload Destination and not nested in sub-folders.

Comment: thank you, but your answer doesn't help me. If i'm an add-on expect i wouldn't be asking the question.  Can we modify safecracker file to tell it to look for upload directory specified in the safecracker tags.

Comment: Why would you want to *hack* SafeCracker's code or its bundled fieldtype, when there's a [Developer API](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/) that allows you to extend ExpressionEngine's functionality? To achieve the functionality you desire, your best solution is to write a plugin or fieldtype. Here's [a simplified example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171828/expressionengine-tags-inside-php/6192200#6192200) to get you started.

Comment: just Little confused about how this would work. Do you mean write a plugin just for the file field. Let's say i create a plugin for file upload that accept file path as a tag property. `{exp:fileupload property='/path/'}` How would that interact with saef. Will it be based on submit click.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, since SafeCracker doesn't have any extension hooks, and there are no add-ons I know of that allow this specific behaviour, I'd make a copy of SafeCracker File and alter it to add this functionality. Otherwise, you're just starting from scratch with your own "upload file" fieldtype.

You'll want to look at around line 148 in ft.safecracker_file.php, and add a wee bit of code to check to see if a directory exists with the logged-in user's screen name or what have you ([see how to get this here](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/usage/session.html#user_data)), create it if it doesn't, then append that directory name to to the upload path:

```
$data = $this->EE->filemanager->upload_file($this->settings['safecracker_upload_dir'].'/'.$users_directory_name, $field_name);
```

That should get you started I think.

Comment: This seems to be sensible solution. I will try it out.

Comment: This doesn't work. When uploading an image, it gives the error `You have not specified any allowed file types.The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.`

Comment: What kind of file are you trying to upload? Do you have XSS filtering turned on?

Comment: I tried to upload a gif file. This is what i did for testing `$data = $this->EE->sc_filemanager->upload_file($this->settings['safecracker_upload_dir'].'/test/', $field_name);`. I created the test folder before testing. But it gave me the filetype error. if i remove `'./test/'`then it works.

Comment: Apologies, my mistake. `$this->settings['safecracker_upload_dir']` is not a directory path, but the integer ID of a predefined upload directory in EE, which is what the Filemanager class' `upload_file` function requires. You may need to just dig-in and write your own fieldtype for this.